# How to get expired Google Play subscriptions?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

Is there a way to get a user's expired subscriptions from Google Play? I am making a magazine-style app, and I want users to have access to content that was published while their subscription was active, regardless of whether they currently have a subscription. For example, if the user buys a month's subscription on the 1st June, then cancels it before the end of the June, from July onwards they should still have access to any content published in June.

Using Google's `IabHelper.java` example library, there doesn't seem to be a way. Continuing the above example, starting from July the `queryInventory()` methods no longer show the subscription at all. That prevents us from retrieving the `purchaseToken`, which in turn prevents us from using the Google Play Developer API. (As documented [here](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get), the `Purchases.Subscriptions:get()`  method requires the token.)

I realise we can locally cache the tokens when the user makes a purchase, but that doesn't work across multiple devices. To keep their purchases on multiple devices, we'd need to store the purchase tokens on a server. However, that would require that the user have a way to log in to our server in order to retrieve their tokens, which adds more complexity.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Hello,have u successfully implemented aubscriptions?? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756889/unable-to-test-in-app-subscription

Comment: Did you have found a way to solve this? I am also struggling with this.

Comment: @burdentao I just ended up creating a server and making them log in.